# str.replace() bug? javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```js
const str = 'test'
const newStr = str.replace(str[3],str[3].toUpperCase())
console.log(newStr) // output: 'Test'

const str2 = 'hello'
const newStr2 = str2.replace(str2[3],str2[3].toUpperCase())
console.log(newStr2) // output: 'heLlo'
```

what does go wrong?

expecting result: `'tesT'`

expecting result: `'helLo'`

Comment: The first argument to `.replace()` is interpreted as a **regular expression**. Thus it replaces the *first* "t" in "test".

Comment: `str.replace()` replaces the first match of the character. So the first one replaces the first `t`, the second one replaces the first `l`. It doesn't matter that you got the `t` or `l` by indexing a different element.

Comment: @Pointy No, it's not converted to a regular expression. You can pass either a regexp or a string, and the string is interpreted literally.

Comment: @Barmar yes but it's treated like a regular expression, more or less, so the "t" matches the first "t" in the source string.

Comment: The fact that it matches the first `t` has nothing to do with whether it's treated like a regexp. It's treated as a string, and replaces the first occurrence of that string.

Comment: Fine, but the point is the result is "Test" and not "tesT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.replace( x, y)` Would replace the first occurance of `x` with `y`

> The replace() method returns a new string with one, some, or all
> matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a
> string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function
> called for each match. If pattern is a string, only the first
> occurrence will be replaced. The original string is left unchanged.